# Prevent restkit from encoding my date query string arguments in get

Tags: restkit, nsdateformatter, restkit-0.20

Restkit is encoding my date objects, so that the url it produces looks like this:

appointments?enddate=2013-12-21T04%3A00%3A00.000&startdate=2013-12-21T04%3A00%3A00.000

However, I need them to look like this:
appointments?enddate=2013-12-20T21:00:00Z&startdate=2013-12-10T09:00:00Z

Here's my code..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

    [RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:@"appointments" parameters:@{
            @"startdate" : [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate],
            @"enddate" : [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endDate],
    }
                                            success:
                                                    ^(
                                                            RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult
                                                            *mappingResult) {
                                                        if (blockSelf.dayButton.isSelected)
                                                        {
                                                            blockSelf.dayView.appointmentsForTimeRange = mappingResult.array;
                                                        } else
                                                        {
                                                            blockSelf.weekView.appointmentsForTimeRange = mappingResult.array;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                            failure:
                                                    ^(
                                                            RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError
                                                            *error) {
                                                        LogVerbose(@"error %@", error);
                                                    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

RestKit is doing exactly what you're asking it. It isn't changing the date format. `%3A` is the URL encoded version of colon. If you need the date format to be different then you need to change the date format string. Perhaps to:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

(Check the date formatted spec for exactly what to use).